# Alternative to Clonezilla to clone semi-faulty hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, clone, clonezilla

For the past few weeks, Windows 7 started locking tight at random.

Originally, I assumed it could be a bug in Flash or the video driver, as it seemed to happen when I was watching videos through Google Chrome, but it kept doing the same thing with Firefox.

I figured it could be a hardware issue, and ran the open-source CrystalDiskInfo utility today, which warned me that the system disk (first partition on disk) had some issues.

So I just bought a new SATA disk of the exact same size as the dying system disk, and tried to run Clonezilla to clone the old disk onto the new one.

However, Clonezilla fails after a few minutes with several occurences of the following error:

```
May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474491] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474515] ata2.00: BMDMA stat 0x24 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474530] ata2.00: failed command: READ DMA May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474549] ata2.00: cmd c8/00:08:48:82:da/00:00:00:00:00/e4 tag 0 dma 4096 in May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474550]          res 51/40:00:48:82:da/00:00:00:00:00/e4 Emask 0x9 (media error) May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474600] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR } May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.474615] ata2.00: error: { UNC } May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496400] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496409] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [
2189.496411] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496415] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] May 6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496419] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex): May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [
2189.496421]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00  May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496428]         04 da 82 48  May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496431] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496436] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 da 82 48 00 00 08 00 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496444] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 81429064 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496465] quiet_error: 22 callbacks suppressed May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496468] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427016 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [
2189.496493] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427017 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496558] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427018 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [
2189.496617] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427019 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496676] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427020 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [
2189.496735] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427021 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496795] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427022 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [
2189.496854] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 81427023 May  6 23:23:06 precise kernel: [ 2189.496923] ata2: EH complete
```

I don't know how good a job Clonezilla does with so-so disks. Before giving up, is there a better utility you would recommend, that would try several times, and possibly perform a slower job before failing?

Thank you.

Comment: Any tool you ran you have to use the option to skip over any bad sectors.  But we can't list those alternatives because software recommendations are not on topic.  There are tons of questions on this website website which suggest tools like CloneZilla anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. A better solution is using an application that 1) boots from a USB key instead of running within Windows and 2) handles faulty sectors unlike CZ which just gives up altogether.

Both answers below look good.

Comment: There are lots of tools that provided Windows can still boot could create an image and ignore the bad sectors.  I am pretty sure Clonezilla can be configured to ignore sector errors.

Comment: @OverTheRainbow You can make a bootable [Clonezilla live USB](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php). Also, you can continue when there are disk read errors if you enable the `-rescue` parameter (available under the [Expert mode](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php)).

Answer (score 3):

[gnu ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) from a livecd is probably the best bet here. It'll copy out all 'easy' to copy data, then do multiple passes on bad data to try to recover as much of it as possible - I have a more in depth answer on [dd varients](https://superuser.com/questions/355310/dd-rescue-vs-dcfldd-vs-dd/355322#355322) here. I'd back up to an image, then restore it to my new drive. I'd then probably run chkdsk to be sure everything is fine.

I'd also suggest having proper, pre-emptive backups in future

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are asking for but the best tool I know of for situations like yours is [Spinrite](http://grc.com). Unfortunately it is quite expensive USD90 or so but it is a life-saver and I've used it on several otherwise unrecoverable disks.

It will try very hard indeed to recover every part of a disk and often succeeds, it is likely (but not guaranteed of course) to be able to recover the disk sufficiently that CloneZilla will be able to complete.

Otherwise, I think that you will need to backup at a file level and reinstall from scratch.