# How to mount a HDD for forensics?

Tags: linux, mount, forensics

What command flags are needed with Linux's `mount` to mount a hard drive without leaving any trace on it? Do I just need `noatime`?

Comment: If you mount it as read-only, you will not be able to change it in any way.

Comment: Alright, that's good. Doing so will prevent anyone from ever knowing I LiveUSB'ed into their computer and looked at their hard drive?

I could still copy files off it though, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are write blockers needed when there is mount with read-only?](http://superuser.com/questions/846546/why-are-write-blockers-needed-when-there-is-mount-with-read-only)

Comment: Yes to both, unless the BIOS has some sort of trace in it.

Comment: I have just looked at @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's link, and it seems I was a little simplistic. You should read the answers there.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but would it be acceptable for you to "dd" the entire device to something like a file on another disk and the mount the file as a loopback device? I've done this before with damaged SD cards in order to recover lost pictures so that I don't disturb the original device.