# How to boot Ubuntu as read-only… using overlayroot is apparently not enough?

Tags: filesystems

Trying to boot Ubuntu installed to disk as read-only.

Installed `overlayroot` and set `overlayroot` to `tmpfs`.

```
$ sudo apt install -y overlayroot

$ sudo sed -i 's/overlayroot=""/overlayroot="tmpfs"/g' /etc/overlayroot.conf

$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Running `sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /dev/rdisk5s1 /dev/rdisk5s2` reveals that checksum of `/dev/rdisk5s2` changes… **why?**

**How can one make disk forensically read-only?**

Test one…

```
$ sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /dev/rdisk5s1 /dev/rdisk5s2
SHA512(/dev/rdisk5s1)= c533e6d472f9a36009f7dc11c337fe0da71b31e6d77fe40e96a7ea92e4711604c9044b40334782a35ddfbf2537a4bebb6602c6f576ce93092172c98a9fe59672
SHA512(/dev/rdisk5s2)= 072dc609ed857b9cb758b688bd659672db9702d218388e5c4e24ad324f7098c01bacf93742f7cbb28a1387179423f9e90596503b1b4917df16c63b7aaee5b30d
```

Reboot, do stuff, test two…

```
$ sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /dev/rdisk5s1 /dev/rdisk5s2
SHA512(/dev/rdisk5s1)= c533e6d472f9a36009f7dc11c337fe0da71b31e6d77fe40e96a7ea92e4711604c9044b40334782a35ddfbf2537a4bebb6602c6f576ce93092172c98a9fe59672
SHA512(/dev/rdisk5s2)= 9fac42f8e27583a2c2489f4888d72d4d662990535cd5355d01f80d94464572b3669d8b1d9b57b0776b65525d3ce5293e6ee52c16bdc0635f2517ad9aecfd62b
```

Comment: Hardware solution: clone disk, and *on the clone* set security permissions to read-only. Forensic analysis should not affect the original media.

Comment: Thanks for helping out… trying to make sure one can use Ubuntu without data persistence (similar to how Tails works).

Comment: One can boot a fully-functional Ubuntu from DVD, which is immutable, *but* one **can** make changes (to the OS and to the file system in RAM) while operating, such as downloading additional software and installing it. *However*, those changes do *not* persist after reboot. Not sure if that answers your question, though. Are you looking for a kiosk mode? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials?q=kiosk

Comment: For the record, in your post you mentioned nothing about actually setting any mountpoint (including but not limited to `/`) to `ro` or enabling this overlayroot thing. Also, for `/` if you set `ro` in fstab for its entry (if any) instead of in the kernel command line, the `/` filesystem might still be mounted `rw` for a while every boot.

Comment: Thanks to @secfren’s answer, I believe the issue might be caused to `noauto` flag missing… investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues was caused by journaling file system… using ext2, checksum no longer changes.

That said, I also had to disable `fsck.repair` when using read-only disk (example: [datAshur PRO²](https://istorage-uk.com/product/datashur-pro2/) set to read-only).

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/quiet splash/fsck.repair=no quiet splash/g' /etc/default/grub

$ sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 1):

> /dev/rdisk5s2 changes… why?

Analyze it. Compare between boots. Maybe use a smaller test disk (VM).

Related (and maybe the reason you are seeing changes): [Why are write blockers needed when there is mount with read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/846546/why-are-write-blockers-needed-when-there-is-mount-with-read-only)

I don't know what both of these partitions are, but I doubt both are root. And I guess overlayroot just works for root.

If you want it read-only as in the case of Tails you need a hardware write blocker. Like USB-SATA/SSD/NVME adapter with write block switch though you theoretically still could work around that.
The non-persistence of Tails comes from the media it runs from (DVD, USB is rw, RAM).

If the underlying hardware is read-write and the OS is being made RO only by software then someone can work around that just by remounting the root filesystem RW.